# How to set values based on a list in Pandas (python)

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, matching

I have a maybe a hopefully easy question that I wasn't able to find an answer on stack.

I have a a dataframe (df) and I want to set a value (some_value) if a value from the column 'month' is in a list (some_list).

e.g.

> ```
> df[df['month'].isin(some_list)] = some_value
> ```

It's barfing up an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'view'.

Any helpful direction would be awesome.

[edit]:

```
some_list = [4,5,6,7]
some_value = 100
```

df.month is a value from 1 - 12

> df.columns = ['datetime','weekday','hour','month','value']

I realize I also want to find out the index of the rows which isin some_list then use those indices to set the value of another column ('value') to some_value.  Apologies for not writing that originally.

Comment: Your example line `df[df['month'].isin(some_list)] = some_value` works fine when I try it on some toy data, you need to provide more details about your actual data and probably some more example code so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: thanks @Marius - added some info in the edits ... this help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question still doesn't seem to have enough information to find the real problem. This quick example shows that your attempt can work just fine:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [4, 5, 6], 'month': [1, 2, 3]})
some_list = [2, 3]
df[df['month'].isin(some_list)] = 99
df
Out[13]: 
   month   x
0      1   4
1     99  99
2     99  99
```

...suggesting that your problem is more likely because you've mixed up the types of your variables. Currently the only thing I can suggest is only doing the assignment to specific columns, as you may be trying to assign an int value to a datetime column or something, e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [4, 5, 6], 'month': [1, 2, 3]})
some_list = [2, 3]
df.loc[df['month'].isin(some_list), 'x'] = 99
df
Out[14]: 
   month   x
0      1   4
1      2  99
2      3  99
```

Comment: Nailed it in your second answer -- I didn't realize I could use df.loc but was trying to use df.ix  -- super helpful. Thanks Marius

Comment: can I use two isin statements within that df.loc[df['month'].isin(some_list), 'x'] = 99 ... like df.loc[df['month'].isin(some_list) and df['day'].isin(some_other_list), 'x'] = 99

Comment: @SteelyDanish yeah that should be fine, you just need to use `&` instead of `and` because you're comparing vectors, not single values