# Replace values of one column based off list of IDs in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace values of the Store column but only for specific IDs in a list (this could be a list of thousands of IDs)

```
ID#     Fruit      Store 
1234    Apple      Whole Foods
4567    Banana     Trader Joe's
6789    Apple      Trader Joe's
7890    Kiwi       Shop Rite
```

I want only ID# in a list ['1234,'6789','7890'] Store Name to be changed to "Walmart"

Desired Dataframe:

```
ID#     Fruit      Store 
1234    Apple      Walmart
4567    Banana     Trader Joe's
6789    Apple      Walmart
7890    Kiwi       Walmart
```

What is the quickest way to do this in python/pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use boolean and `.loc` notation `df.loc[df['ID'].isin(['1234,'6789','7890']),'Store'] = 'Walmart'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set values based on a list in Pandas (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128477/how-to-set-values-based-on-a-list-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use loc access with `isin`:

```
df.loc[df['ID#'].isin( ['1234','6789','7890']), 'Store'] = 'Walmart'
```

Output:

```
    ID#   Fruit         Store
0  1234   Apple       Walmart
1  4567  Banana  Trader Joe's
2  6789   Apple       Walmart
3  7890    Kiwi       Walmart
```